# Moving textfield with mouse

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textbox

This is the code I have for creating a text box when clicking a button:

```
TextBoxButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addTextBox);

function addTextBox(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    myFont = new Font2();
    typeText:TextField = new TextField();
    typeText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
    ttypeTextext.x = 540;
    typeTexteText.width = 175;
    ttypeTextText.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
    typeTexteText.text = "Your text here";

    //Adding to the stage.
    newLayer.addChild(typeableText);
}
```

My question is: how do I modify this code so that the user can drag and drop the text to wherever he/she wants on the stage using the mouse?

EDIT: Some further code:

```
TextBoxButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addTextBox);

function addTextBox(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var myFont = new Font2();
    var typeableText:TextField = new TextField();
    typeableText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
    typeableText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
    typeableText.embedFonts = true;
    typeableText.x = 540;
    typeableText.y = 400;
    typeableText.width = 175;
    typeableText.height = 200;
    typeableText.wordWrap = true;
    typeableText.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
    typeableText.text = "Your text here";
    interfaceLayer.buttonMode = true;
    //Adding to the stage.
    appLayer.addChild(typeableText);
    if (typeableText.stage)
    {
        SideBarText.removeChild(TextBoxButton);
    }
}

appLayer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragText);
appLayer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragText);

function dragText(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    appLayer.startDrag();
}

function stopDragText(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    appLayer.stopDrag();
}
```

Comment: set buttonMode on interfaceLayer to true, add an event listener for mouse down on interfaceLayer and in the handler do `interfaceLayer.startDrag()` and add an event listener on the stage object for mouse up and in it do `interfaceLayer.stopDrag()`

Comment: The only problem with this is that there are other UI elements on the interfaceLayer that will then move when trying to move just the text field.

Comment: put a displayobject between the textfield and the `interfaceLayer` to hold your textfield, and apply the above to that displayobject

Comment: Ah got it, thanks. Obviously with my text field being editable, when I click and drag the text after typing, the cursor sort of still highlights letters. Is there any way of stopping the text cursor from showing and highlighting the text only whilst it is being moved?

Comment: yes, you can temporarily or permanently set the `.selectable` property to false

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply it to the text with the updated code I have. The text is the `typeableText` textfield.